# Duplicate row in table when sending a variable from as3 to mysql database

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, duplicates, rows

I'm working on a flash content on my website whit two input boxes and a submit button.
The user should fill the boxes (school and student) and submits.
The database table was one auto-increment column and columns for each variable.
The problem is when the values are submitted and sended, the table increment 2 rows with the same values.
Here are my codes:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

validate_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, Validate);

function Validate (e:Event)     {
var Variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var Request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("participant.php");
var Loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

Variables.school = escape(school_txt.text);
Variables.student = escape(student_txt.text);
Request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
Request.data = Variables;
Loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
Loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Complete);
Loader.load(Request);

navigateToURL(Request, "participant.php");
}

function Complete(e:Event) {
ntext = unescape(e.target.data.x);
gotoAndStop(2);
}

<?php
$school = urldecode($_POST['school']);
$student = urldecode($_POST['student']);
$flag = 0;

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$connection) {
die (mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("db_school", $connection);
if (!$db_select) {
die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO School (school, student, flag)
VALUES ('$school','$student','$flag')") 
or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($connection)) {
mysql_close($connection);
}

echo "x=participation successfully record";
?>
```

So what's wrong with it?

Comment: It can be so if you have two or more same EventListeners on your button. Are you sure there is only one? Try to debug your code and find out either the listener works twice.

Comment: No, I check and the button has one EventListener.

Comment: I also write this code in php file,

Comment: I also write this code in php file:                                 $text = var_export($_POST, true);
echo urldecode($text);

Comment: I also write this code in php file:                                  $text = var_export($_POST, true);                                       echo urldecode($text);                                                     and the screen shows:                                                      array ( 'student' => 'Paul', 'school' => 'London', )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have two commands, which both do the same thing:

```
Loader.load(Request);

navigateToURL(Request, "participant.php");
```

So you need to use only one of them. To get an appropriate response in your Complete() function, use the first one.

I have tried to do it by myself. It works for both commands well! (the second command does not cause the reaction in Flex, because it is not supposed to do it).